# How do I modify this code to make every even number index in an array true?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, boolean

Here's what I have:

```
  boolean[] even = new boolean[array.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      even[i] = (array[i] % 2) == 0;
  }
```

I want indexes `(0,2,4,6,8,etc)` to be true, and indexes `(1,3,5,7,9,etc)` to be false

I think this code is more accurate to what I'm trying to do, but it won't compile.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
      int val = (array[i] % 2);
      if(val == 0)
          array[i] = true;
      else
          array[i] = false;
  }
```

Comment: You should correct array[i] % 2 in i % 2, i guess.

Comment: You want `i % 2` instead of `array[i] % 2`, surely?

Answer (score 1):

In the first snippet, change:

```
  even[i] = (array[i] % 2) == 0;
```

to:

```
  even[i] = (i % 2) == 0;
```

In the second snippet, change:

```
int val = (array[i] % 2);
```

to:

```
int val = i % 2;
```

Comment: BTW `& 1` is much faster than `% 2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `even[i] = true` instead of `array[i] = true`. I am assuming array is an array of integers and even is an array of boolean values. So, you need to assign the boolean value to the index of a boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is really small:

You are not checking whether your index is divisible by two, but rather, if the value in the array is divisible by 2.

```
boolean[] even = new boolean[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < even.length ; i++)
{
if(i % 2 == 0)
    even[i] = true;
else
    even[i] = false;
}
```

Edit: Apparently everyone takes about the same length of time to answer, and now we have seventy identical answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you're writing to the array `even`, which is an array of booleans.

In the second example, you're writing to the array `array`, which (while not shown) must be an array of integers, as that's where you're reading the integers from.

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    int val = (array[i] % 2);
    if(val == 0)
        even[i] = true;
    else
        even[i] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of performing a modulus and a branch which are both expensive operations you can use some loop unrolling and optimise the loop.

```
boolean[] even = new boolean[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    even[i] = true;
    // not needed as boolean[] are set to all false by default
    // even[i+1] = false;
}
```

BTW a boolean[] uses one *byte* per value on most platforms.  A more efficient approach might be to use a BitSet.

```
BitSet even = new BitSet(array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i += 2)
     even.set(i);
```

This will use as little as 1/8th of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length ; i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        array[i] = true;
    }
    else{
        array[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code can be modified to the following:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {

  if(array[i]%2==0)
      even[i] = true; //assign to even , not array
  else
      even[i] = false; //assign to even, not array
  }
```

to get what you want.